# Replace extraspaces of a string after pattern matching using rwcrexpr in C++

Tags: c++, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I have a string like below

```
std::string = "S.ID="1234" S.NAME="Sachin"    S.NICKNAME="God  of  cricket" S.CITY="MUMBAI";
```

I need to replace each extra spaces after the pattern ="*" with a single space
using RWCRexpr

Any help on this?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of strings you want to match and not match? Also the code you provided wont compile

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression [`\s*=\s*"\[^\"\]*"(\s{2,})`](https://regex101.com/r/xO7eI0/1) will match your extra spaces.

Hovewer, according to the online documentation, [`RWCRexpr` is deprecated](http://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwcrexpr.html#sec3) and your should use [`RWTRegex<T>`](http://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwtregex.html) instead.